# раскрыть окно браузера на полный экран

Tags: javascript

делаю так:

```
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
```

но браузер пишет

```
Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

можно как-либо сделать чтобы при открытии странички она на весь экран отобразилась автоматом???

Comment: боюсь что нет, иначе были бы сайты, где это используется чтобы пользователь не смог уйти

Comment: Думаю, что автоматически при открытии страницы такое сделать нельзя будет. Вот тут посмотрите: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_fullscreen2

Comment: Никак нельзя, это защита браузера. Только по инициативе пользователя.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а имитировать нажатие кнопки (чтобы браузер подумал, что это пользователь)?

Comment: есть DispatchEvent, но боюсь не поможет, это сделано умышленно в целях безопасности

Comment: кстати а зачем вам это https://tinyurl.com/y32arsjo

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц хаха. Тоже нельзя, браузер не дураки писали

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не поверите )заказчик требует )

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц не берите заказы, не убедившись в технической осуществимости

Comment: слушайте только компетентных коллег

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function () {

                var element = document.body;
                var req = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen;

                if(req)
                    req.call(element);
                else
                {
                    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
                    wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
                }

                return false;

            });
```

[источник](http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript/thread561981.html)

Для вашего удобства разработано [api](https://habr.com/ru/post/184926/) - которое позволяет переводить ТОЛЬКО нужный вам элемент в полноэкранный режим

Если нужно автоматом попробуйте эмитировать нажатие клавиши в зависимость от браузера или элемента, который нужно перевести в полноэкранный режим